# Hybris - How do i add the SmartEdit extension to an existing Project

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

the title says it. 
I created a custom project with modulegen and used the accelerator template as a base. The apparel storefront and backoffice is present, however i wanted to try out the SmartEdit and WCMS functions.

What extensions do i have to add to my localextensions.xml file to get SmartEdit to work?
I tried to add

```
<extension name='cmssmartedit' />
```

but that failed after the ant clean build.

Comment: which Hybris version are you using?

Comment: 1811.6, thanks for the fast reply

Answer (score 1):

Refer [Installing SmartEdit](https://help.sap.com/viewer/86dd1373053a4c2da8f9885cc9fbe55d/1811/en-US/0955af7dd5154a8db28dfce327d8dae5.html?q=SmartEdit) document for the detail steps

If you are manually installing SmartEdit then below are the extensions and addon you need

```
cmsbackoffice
cmssmartedit
cmssmarteditwebservices
cmswebservices
permissionswebservices
previewwebservices
smartedit
smarteditaddon
smarteditwebservices
ysmarteditmodule (if you want to extend the SAP Commerce framework or CMS functionality)
```

Must install the smarteditaddon AddOn as follows:

```
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames=smarteditaddon -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront=<your_custom_storefront>
```

Comment: When trying to add the addon i get an error message that my storefront extension is not included in my localextensions.xml.
"storefront extension 'pbacceleratorstorefront' is not added to localextensions.xml. Please include the pbacceleratorstorefront extension in your localextensions.xml"

It is added, but only by directory and not by name, could that be a problem?

"<extension dir="/home/pbuser/hybris_pb/hybris/bin/custom/pbaccelerator/pbacceleratorstorefront"/>"

Comment: Add it like `<extension name="pbacceleratorstorefront"/>`